# GoToState not working on controltemplated usercontrol based on combobox

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, combobox, controltemplate, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to create a custom combobox that shows a loading animation when a bool property is set on it (e.g. IsLoading).

I've created a control template in Blend based on the combobox, and added a textblock inside the togglebutton template. In the code behind I'm calling VisualStateManager.GoToState but it always returns false. I was trying to move to a custom state initially, but I can't even move to states such as Disabled or MouseOver.

I have a usercontrol that just contains a combobox and the style is set to my combobox style containing the control template. I presume GoToState fails because the state is not on the control itself, but inside the combobox. How can I access this?

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this as there are no errors.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem! I had the Visual States defined within a grid in the ControlTemplate.

```
        <Style x:Key="Image3TextRowButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
                        ...
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            ...
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Active">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundActiveBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotActive" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Griesser.Presentation.ContactCenterClient.Client.Control.Image3TextRowButtonUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="Image3TextRowButton">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Command="{Binding Command, ElementName=Image3TextRowButton}" Style="{StaticResource Image3TextRowButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

In the code behind I am looking first for the RootGrid and then use GoToElementState:

```
        private void ChangeVisualActiveState(bool useTransitions)
    {
        // Search RootGrid, because the Visual States are defined in the ControlTemplate!
        FrameworkElement dt = btn.Template.FindName("RootGrid", btn) as FrameworkElement;

        if (IsActive)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(dt, "Active", useTransitions);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(dt, "NotActive", useTransitions);
        }
    }
```